# Badges don't have rounded corners on IE

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, internet-explorer

I know it's really irrelevant, but on IE8 the badges look like this:

[image]

Or nobody here cares about iE?

Comment: What are you talking about. Internet Evil? Inappropriate Extremists?

Comment: Would it be rude of me to point and laugh?

Comment: [Here is an nickel, kid. Get yourself a better browser.](http://ozguru.mu.nu/Photos/2005-11-11--Dilbert_Unix.jpg)

Comment: @dmckee There are computers where you are stuck with IE

Comment: @perbert I can't

Comment: @NullUser Sure, you can be stuck in a specified environment. Most of us have been at one time or another, but the "pain" of having square badges simply doesn't engage my sympathy. Man up, if that's the worth thing that happens to you all day you doing pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 and IE8 don't support any rational `border-radius` CSS. Perhaps IE9 will?

Comment: We can only hope... not that I'd actually use it anyway.

Comment: Yes, Jeff, [IE9](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Default.html) will support `border-radius`.

Comment: @null once IE9 is a public release, we'll look at adding that.

Comment: What about Opera? Recent releases of Opera support `border-radius` too. Or, is Opera-based traffic too little to justify that?

Comment: @Jeff: Now there is a public release, will this be reconsidered?

Comment: @richard doesn't IE9 support the various existing border-radius'es? In general we don't begin supporting a browser until it's a public release.

Comment: @Jeff: 1. AFAIAA IE doesn't support anything from other browswers own CSS namespace (i.e. `-moz-` etc.). 2. "Public release": do you mean RTM or just "public"? 3. /status-by-design/status-planned/?

Answer (score 0):

The badges use `-moz-border-radius`, so I think this is by design

Comment: It's worth noting they also use `-webkit-border-radius` as well, so it's not *just* Mozilla/Firefox support :)

Comment: @Nick - Huh, I can't find -webkit... in .badge or .badge-tag or the entire CSS files. I only see -moz... (using Firebug)

Comment: @Peter: because the -... styles are intended to be browser-specific. If Firebug showed -webkit styles, then Firefox would be *recognizing* webkit styles, and that defeats the whole purpose (preliminary implementations that don't necessary match the standard).

Comment: @Shoq - Whoops, I thought the rules would still show up if I browse the CSS files through Firebug, even if they're not implemented.